# gitignore is not ignoring the files I added

Tags: github, gitignore, asp.net-core-3.1

The code below is what I have tried in the .gitignore file. Other folders when I put `logs or **/wwwroot` and save the file, every file in the folder is ignored but this `object` folder in the core project is not ignored somehow.

```
obj/project.assets.json
obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CDS.PORTAL.assets.cache
obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CDS.PORTAL.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CDS.PORTAL.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/staticwebassets/CDS.PORTAL.StaticWebAssets.Manifest.cache
obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/staticwebassets/CDS.PORTAL.StaticWebAssets.xml
```

[image: Screenshot of VS Code]

Comment: i think you should attach your .gitignore

Comment: the code box is the gitignore file contents. The image below shows in VIsual studio code that the files still want to be pushed to the github after I ignired the folder

Comment: please check if the file is already tracked by git, or using `git status` commandline to comfirn, I do not know much about the git extension in vscode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **M** next to the file names in VS Code stands for Modified. See [`git status` modes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format).

Seems like at some point you've added those files to `git`, then added those entries to `.gitignore` later. `git` now *knows* those files exist and keeps track of them, and doesn't automatically rewrite, even though you have a new `.gitignore` list.

If you still want to do this, check this similar question: [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore?rq=1)